# Why does this binomial coefficient develop like this?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

This is the question.

> Suppose a column has $m$ $1$’s and therefore $n − m$ $0$’s, and we randomly
> choose $k$ rows to consider when computing the minhash. Prove that the
> probability of getting “don’t know” as the minhash value for this
> column is at most $\left(\frac{n-k}n\right)^m$.

This is the solution.

> The number of columns with $m$ $1$’s out of $n$ is $nCm$. The number of
> these columns that have no $1$ in one of the $k$ selected rows is $(n-k)Cm$.
> The probability of no $1$ in the chosen $k$ rows is therefore the latter
> divided by the former. If we expand the binomial coefficients in terms
> of factorials, we get $\frac{(n-k)!m!(n-m)!}{m!(n-k-m)!n!}$. The $m!$’s cancel,
> and when we reorganize we can write this expression as $\left(\frac{n-k}n\right)\left(\frac{n-k-1}{n-1}\right)\ldots\left(\frac{n-k-m+1}{n-m+1}\right)$. Each of the $m$ factors is at most $n−kn$. Thus,
> their product is at most $(n−kn)m$.

In the solution, I have a question. Why is $(n-k)Cm$ not $\frac{(n-k)!}{m!(n-k-m)!}$ but $\frac{(n-k)!m!(n-m)!}{m!(n-k-m)!n!}$?

Sorry for poor readability. I don't know how to put fractions. Please tell me how to put it, and I will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The fraction

$$\frac{(n-k)!m!(n-m)!}{m!(n-k-m)!n!}$$

isn’t $\binom{n-k}m$: it’s

$$\frac{\binom{n-k}m}{\binom{n}m}\,,$$

the probability of no $1$ in the chosen $k$ rows.

Comment: Now I understand. I guess I misunderstood the solution. Thank you.

Comment: @SeHoon: You’re welcome.

Comment: I have another question. "Suppose a column has m 1’s and therefore n−m 0’s"
What does this mean exactly?

Comment: @SeHoon: I don’t know enough about the context to be sure, but it sounds like you’re dealing with an array of $0$s and $1$s in which each column has $n$ cells: if $m$ of these cells contain $1$s, the other $n-m$ cells must contain $0$s.

Comment: @Brain M. Scoot: Thank you for your kind answer.

Comment: @SeHoon: You’re welcome.